# DX NameSpace understanding

Tags: c#, devexpress

Having problems with C# 1st project. I copied form from another project into mine.

That form have namespace from the original project. And looks like this

```
namespace DevExpress.ProductsDemo.Win.Forms {
    public partial class EditPutnik : XtraForm
    {
        public EditPutnik()
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Now i want to change namespace to my project file which is dx_Prijave as used on the Main form

```
namespace dx_Prijave
{
    public partial class Main : DevExpress.XtraBars.Ribbon.RibbonForm
    {
        public Main()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

but i get bunch of errors such as :

[image]

More info :

[image]
[image]

Comment: I am guessing you didn't edit and change the namespace in the EditF.Designer.cs file. Right-click on this file in the solution explorer and click on View Code. You may need to expand the main EditF.cs file to see it in the tree.

Comment: changing on designer and form didnt fix my prooblem :(

Comment: Did you change the class name to EditPutnik in designer file?

Comment: @MarkoJuvančič pogledaj sad . See updated post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open `EditF.Designer.cs` file (not the visual designer, but the C# code file) and change the namespace. Make sure to rename your class to EditPutnik.

If it still doesn't work, I'd suggest to [simply add a new XtraForm](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/8437/Controls-and-Libraries/Forms-and-User-Controls/Examples/How-to-Add-New-XtraForm-RibbonForm-and-XtraUserControl-to-Your-Project) to your project and then copy the form's content from another project.

Comment: @t3cho, I don't see any problems at those screenshots. In my opinion, adding an empty XtraForm and checking if it works (then adding your copied content if it does) is the fastest way to solve the problem.

Comment: Yes but seems like there is a problem with xtra form layoutControlGroup it doesn't allow copy to an empty form

Comment: @t3cho, I meant copying C# code to both <Your new Form>.Designer.cs and <Your new Form>.cs, without even touching the visual from designer.